# Redirect user to a specific URL after he Likes the page?

Tags: facebook, onclick, facebook-like, redirect, facebook-likebox

Is it possible with the Facebook OpenGraph's and API's to redirect user to a specific URL after he Likes a certain page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.

rather than using a like social widget (which is the common way to like a page), you should implement your own button or link, which calls a Graph API method to like the page, then in use the api callback to navigate the user to a different url.

You can use facebook [javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) to call a [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) method.

in this example:

```
FB.api(pageId +  '/likes', 'post' ,function(response) {
    //redirect the user to a page;
});
```

using "post" in the second parameter will like, using "delete" in the second param will "unlike"